# What is a reliable Monero remote nodes that is used in the CakeWallet mobile app?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, remote-node, cakewallet

I tried many of the monero nodes on monero world and many of them do not connect reliably when using the wallet cli. I find the cake wallet mobile app remote node to be most reliable. What is the remote node connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following cakewallet remote nodes as used in the mobile wallets:

- East coast:

  xmr-node-usa-east.cakewallet.com:18081
- West coast:

  xmr-node-usa-west.cakewallet.com:18081

If your using the monero wallet cli command, you use it like this:

> ./monero-wallet-cli  --wallet-file=MY_WALLET_FILE --daemon-address
> xmr-node-usa-east.cakewallet.com:18081

Answer (score 1):

The default node `xmr-node.cakewallet.com:18081` should work just fine ([live status](https://nodes.monero.com/history/xmr-node-cakewallet-com-18081)).

You can see other nodes at https://nodes.monero.com or https://monero.fail